# I can not get correct amountOut by quoteExactInputSingle -uniswap-v3-quoter

Tags: javascript, pool, web3js, price, uniswap

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const fs = require('fs')

let web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:8545')

let myABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./0_abi/Quoter.abi').toString())

let addrQuoter = '0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6' // quoter
let addrTokenIn = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2' // ETH
let addrTokenOut = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F' // DAI

let fee = 500 // 0.05%
let amountIn = 3
let sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0

let myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myABI, addrQuoter)

myContract.methods.quoteExactInputSingle(
    addrTokenIn,
    addrTokenOut,
    fee,
    amountIn,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96).call((err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(res)
})
```

if amountIn is 1, res is 0 
if amountIn is 2, res is 2730, close to the real market price 
if amountIn is 3, res is 5461, 
... 
so the real amountIn is (amountIn - 1) 
why? 
And the liquidity is limited. But as the amountIn become bigger, the amountOut is bigger. \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 means 1 wei, not 1 ether. So, if amountIn is 1, the amountIn is paid for fee totally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).